# git clone not working in jenkins shell script

Tags: git, shell, jenkins

I am setting up jenkins build pipeline and in one of the build steps, I am trying to git clone a repository.

Build steps(execute shell):

`git clone git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git`

It fails at this step with

```
10:14:01 Permission denied (publickey).
10:14:01 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
10:14:01 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
10:14:01 Finished: FAILURE
```

However, while setting up the repo, I have set scm as git and have specified the repository url as `git clone git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git` and this works perfectly.

Any idea what I might be missing here.

Comment: Jenkins runs as its own user. Did you test switching to the Jenkins user and doing a clone?

Comment: Switching user in system or for the github account ?

Comment: switch to the jenkins user on the system and run the clone command yourself from the command line. You prolly didn't setup the github ssh stuff for that user.

Comment: To achieve what @Reck suggest execute `su - jenkins` as superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Github uses an ssh public/private keypair for authentication. When you use github, you need to provide your public key. You probably did that once already, following [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

When you generate a keypair, the default behavior is that **only the user which generated the keypair** has access to it. That means if you generate it as **upr**, the user **jenkins** has no access to the keypair needed to connect to github.

To fix this problem, switch to the jenkins user. If you're in unix, you can do this via

```
sudo su - jenkins
```

Then follow the [keygeneration steps provided by github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/). For Jenkins to use the key, the simplest approach is to create it with no password.

I've not used it, but a [Jenkins plugin like this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) might allow you to use a password protected keypair.

Comment: you prolly want to use sudo su - jenkins: https://superuser.com/questions/453988/whats-the-difference-between-su-with-and-without-hyphen